# Calling back and forth between C and Java over JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a strange stack problem when making calls back and forth between C and Java over JNI.

Our code is a mixture of C and Java modules that can call each other using JNI.

The problem I have seems to occur when the following happens;

C module (CA.c) calls a  Java module (JA.java), which calls a C module (CB.c), which attempts and fails to call a Java module (JB.java).

CB does make some Java calls that work successfully, however JNI seems to start failing once there are a certain number of functions on the stack:

**CB.c**

```
func1() {
   CallJavaViaJNI();  //Works fine
   func2();
   CallJavaViaJNI();  //Works fine
}

func2() {
   CallJavaViaJNI();  //Works fine
   func3();
   CallJavaViaJNI();  //Works fine
}

func3() {
   CallJavaViaJNI();  //Fails
}
```

In the example above, calls to CallJavaViaJNI() will succeed when called from func1() and func2() but fail in func3() (jnienv->ExceptionCheck() returns true).  Also, the calls to CallJavaViaJNI() in func1() and func2() that occur after func3() work.

This is just an example, there may be lot more functions on the stack than this.  It just seems to be that JNI stops working once there is so much on the stack.  after the function is popped off the stack things start working again.

I've tried calling ExceptionDescribe() after ExceptionCheck() returns true, but I get nothing out of it.  Clearing the exception and trying again results in the same.

Is this something to do with the initialisation of JNI?  Do I need to specify a stack size or some other parameter?

When calling back to C from a Java module that's been called from C, is there anything special that needs to be done?  The documentation isn't very clear on this.

I'd appreciate any help or pointers on this.

Comment: What exactly does `CallJavaViaJNI` do? And is it exactly the same thing in all these cases? You say that you got nothing out of `ExceptionDescribe`. Does that mean you didn't find the output helpful, or that you didn't get any output at all? In the latter case, are you sure you haven't redirected STDERR to `/dev/null` or something like that?

Comment: CallJavaViaJNI() would be calling a Java module using something like CallStaticVoidMethod().  After this call, ExceptionCheck() returns true.
As to ExceptionDescribe(), it seems to return an empty string.

Comment: Have you tried to extend the thread stack size?

Comment: I've used `ulimit -s unlimited` which had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work, however it is so simplistic I suspect you are leaving something crucial out of it, can you please post a more accurate illustration of your problem?

I hesitate to guess without more context BUT, I have certainly been in similar situations and have a few ideas.

I am interested in seeing how you construct your java objects, in c++ or java? Are there differences between the instantiation of objects in use between func1(), func2(), and func3()?

Comment: It's difficult to give a more detailed answer that's closer to how our code works.  It's a massive enterprise system, with thousands of modules and millions of lines of code.  I tried to break it down into as simple a problem as possible to post here.  The problematic code works in different scenarios and seems to start failing when there's a lot on the stack.  What's strange is that the C executes fine, it's only the JNI environment that becomes corrupt and it even recovers once functions are popped off the stack.